# Unable to build a Swift package after adding the `RxSwift` package dependency: "product 'RxCocoa' not found"

Tags: xcode, rx-swift, swift-package-manager, rx-cocoa, swift-package

I have created a new Swift package and trying to use the `RxSwift` dependency within it. I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift#swift-package-manager) to add the dependency but my package is unable to build after this with the following error:

> product 'RxCocoa' required by package 'mylibrary' target 'MyLibrary' not found.

My package manifest is here:

```swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.8
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    products: [them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift.git", .exact("6.5.0"))
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            dependencies: ["RxSwift", "RxCocoa"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyLibraryTests",
            dependencies: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ]
)
```

[image]

I'm using `Xcode 14.3`.
How should I add the RxSwift dependency to the package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RxCocoa isn't its own package, it's a product in the RxSwift package. Your dependencies need to be set up like this:

```
dependencies: [
    "RxSwift",
    .product(name: "RxCocoa", package: "RxSwift"),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! And it works great. Although the [RxSwift docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift#swift-package-manager) clearly defines dependency differently and (turned out) incorrectly